# deploy web site asp.net visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ftp, web-deployment

i search a tool for visual studio 2012, i would to deploy my App web site
on the ftp server.

If we can get on right click on the file , "deploy on the server"

or a deploy automatically , to send only aspx , ascx, css, js, bin(dll)  file.

have you an idea to find this ?

thanks
Olivier

Comment: Have you tried this? http://support.winhost.com/KB/a1094/how-do-i-deploy-visual-studio-2012-web-application.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Publish wizard, which is accessible by right-clicking your project and choosing Publish from the context menu. You can publish to IIS, a file path or an FTP server, IIRC.